# How to get a particular value after JSON.stringify()

Tags: javascript

This is the data displaying in console.log.

```
{"data":
    [
        {
            "CloserName":null,
            "agent_id":"10807",
            "AgentName":"TEST",
            "SurveyDate":"02/02/2018 02:18:46 AM",
            "SurveyName":"Ruth  ",
            "state":"West Bengal",
            "phone":"9836969715",
            "status":"Approved",
            "verification_progress":"Pending",
            "survey_id":"1",
            "rejection_remarks":"aa",
            "tl_remarks":"Pending"
        }
    ],
    "count":1
}
```

Can anyone help me display a single value (i.e `survey_id`)? I just want to fetch that `survey_id`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example:

```js
var json = {  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "CloserName":null,
         "agent_id":"10807",
         "AgentName":"TEST",
         "SurveyDate":"02/02/2018 02:18:46 AM",
         "SurveyName":"Ruth ",
         "state":"West Bengal",
         "phone":"9836969715",
         "status":"Approved",
         "verification_progress":"Pending",
         "survey_id":"1",
         "rejection_remarks":"aa",
         "tl_remarks":"Pending"
      }
   ],
   "count":1
}

// get first id
var id = json.data[0].survey_id
console.log(id)

// get all ids
var ids = json.data.map(x => x.survey_id)
console.log(ids)
```

If the JSON is stringified, call `JSON.parse(jsonStr)` first.

Answer (score 3):

You have to parse the JSON-String into an object. After that you can access the data with default object-identifiers.

```js
const object = JSON.parse('{"data":[{"CloserName":null,"agent_id":"10807","AgentName":"TEST","SurveyDate":"02/02/2018 02:18:46 AM","SurveyName":"Ruth ","state":"West Bengal","phone":"9836969715","status":"Approved","verification_progress":"Pending","survey_id":"1","rejection_remarks":"aa","tl_remarks":"Pending"}],"count":1}');
console.log(object.data[0].survey_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your JSON data has been **stringified** (your sample JSON is a valid JSON object, not a string) you would first need to **parse** it, and then get the IDs (assuming you will have more than one item inside the data array) and log them out. There's a few different ways of achieving this:

```js
const stringified = '{"data":[{"CloserName":null,"agent_id":"10807","AgentName":"TEST","SurveyDate":"02/02/2018 02:18:46 AM","SurveyName":"Ruth ","state":"West Bengal","phone":"9836969715","status":"Approved","verification_progress":"Pending","survey_id":"1","rejection_remarks":"aa","tl_remarks":"Pending"}],"count":1}';
    
let parsed = JSON.parse(stringified);
    
parsed = parsed.data.map(item => item.survey_id);
console.log(parsed);
```

You can also just loop over the items in the array and log them one by one using a for loop:

```js
const stringified = '{"data":[{"CloserName":null,"agent_id":"10807","AgentName":"TEST","SurveyDate":"02/02/2018 02:18:46 AM","SurveyName":"Ruth ","state":"West Bengal","phone":"9836969715","status":"Approved","verification_progress":"Pending","survey_id":"1","rejection_remarks":"aa","tl_remarks":"Pending"}],"count":1}';
    
let parsed = JSON.parse(stringified);
    
for (let i = 0; i < parsed.data.length; i++) {
    console.log(parsed.data[i].survey_id);
}
```

Or using a for-of:

```js
const stringified = '{"data":[{"CloserName":null,"agent_id":"10807","AgentName":"TEST","SurveyDate":"02/02/2018 02:18:46 AM","SurveyName":"Ruth ","state":"West Bengal","phone":"9836969715","status":"Approved","verification_progress":"Pending","survey_id":"1","rejection_remarks":"aa","tl_remarks":"Pending"}],"count":1}';

let parsed = JSON.parse(stringified);

for (const item of parsed.data) {
    console.log(item.survey_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your current object structure

Your object

```
var obj = {"data":[{"CloserName":null,"agent_id":"10807","AgentName":"TEST","SurveyDate":"02/02/2018 02:18:46 AM","SurveyName":"Ruth ","state":"West Bengal","phone":"9836969715","status":"Approved","verification_progress":"Pending","survey_id":"1","rejection_remarks":"aa","tl_remarks":"Pending"}],"count":1};
```

Fetching survey_id

```
obj.data[0].survey_id
```